# Jboss No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy my project in JBoss7.1.1 server. But I am getting below message and my project is not getting deployed.

```
 19:13:39,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ips-configuration-dynamic.war" 
 19:13:42,731 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ips-configuration-dynamic]] (MSC service thread 1-8) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 19:13:42,781 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /ips-configuration-dynamic
 19:13:43,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "ips-configuration-dynamic.war"
```

I am using Spring 3.1.1 release jars. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a class implementing `WebApplicationInitializer`? Otherwise you need a web.xml.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I don't have web.xml. Now its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a typical servlet application, you would have a `web.xml` descriptor file to declare your serlvets, filters, listeners, context params, security configuration, etc. for your application. Since servlet 3.0 you can do most of that programmatically.

Servlet 3.0 offers the interface `ServletContainerInitializer`, which you can implement. Your servlet container will look for your implementation of that class in `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file, instantiate it, and call its `onStartup()` method.

Spring has built [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) on top of that interface, as an adapter/helper.

You need either the `web.xml` descriptor or a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` to setup and run your application.

Comment: i already have a web.xml file in my webapp..but eventhen i shows No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath in the console..do i need to add some thing to the web.xml file about the WebApplicationInitializer interface?

Comment: @namxal You need to be running in a Servlet 3.0 compatible servlet container and have your web.xml declare your app as as using Servlet 3.0. The rest will be done by the Servlet container.