# AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer with Jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, embedded-jetty

I'm using Jetty 9.1.0.RC2 and Spring 4.
Have a `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and trying to kick start the initialization with:

```
Server server = new Server();

WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { new AnnotationConfiguration() });
webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

webAppContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*/target/classes/.*");

server.setHandler(webAppContext);
server.start();
server.join();
```

But failing to detect:

```
No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

Comment: can you share your result against this problem?

Comment: can you post the full class? Where do you put that code in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer ?

Comment: did you try using this: `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` class? also you can use this [OpenSource project](https://github.com/foundation-runtime/communication)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. Many more people are facing this issue. Sometimes it is causing error or sometimes it gives just as `info`. **For info**, there is no problem(just like warning). **For error**, there are many types of reason for occuring this error. I am trying to give you some sort of solutions.

---

1. Sometimes spring library and jdk version mismatch causes this error.
   Classes are built in lower version of jdk and trying to run in upper
   version may cause the error. Then we need to change using Eclipse
   from Preferences\Java\Compiler We have to set "compiler compliance
   level: 1.7" and "`Generated .class files compatibility: 1.6`", "Source
   compatibility: 1.6".
2. Some of people get that **log4j wasn't configured to capture error**
   output which was throwing configuration errors in the background.
3. If you are using maven, then WEB-INF directory must be inside your
   webapp. Structure will be `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` It also solves
   this issue.
4. If `"Project -> Build Automatically"` is not selected. You can force
   the "m2e-wtp folder and contents" generation by doing;

   "(right-click
       on your project) -> Maven -> Update Project..."

> Note: make sure the
>       "Clean Projects" option is un-selected. Otherwise the contents of
>       target/classes will be deleted and you're back to square one.

5. Add WebROOT file directory to the default directory, then this
   problem will be solved.

   properties->MyEclipse->Deployment
       Assembly->Add

### Resource Link:

1. [No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321819/no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath/16817018#16817018)
2. [INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938689/info-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath)
3. [only one error: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664924/only-one-error-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath)

---

**For tomcat,**

1. if maven has `tomcat7` plugin but the JRE environment was 1.6. Then
   this problem occurs. Then you need to downgrade `tomcat7` to `tomcat6`
   or upgrade jdk and jre version to 1.7.
2. Sometimes it is need to `stop your tomcat`. Then `clean the project`,
   `clean the server` and `run again your project`. Sometimes caches make this
   issue. After following this way, it may solve.

---

**For JBOSS,**

@`Sotirios Delimanolis` given a very nice answer. That is given below:

In a typical servlet application, you would have a `web.xml` descriptor file to declare your `serlvets, filters, listeners, context params, security configuration, etc`. for your application. Since `servlet 3.0` you can do most of that programmatically.

`Servlet 3.0` offers the interface `ServletContainerInitializer`, which you can implement. Your servlet container will look for your implementation of that class in `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file, instantiate it, and call its `onStartup()` method.

Spring has built [WebApplicationInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) on top of that interface, as an `adapter/helper`.

You need either the `web.xml` descriptor or a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` to setup and run your application.

### Resource Link:

1. [Jboss No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898306/jboss-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath)

---

### A brief detail answer is given below with Jetty:

[Spring WebApplicationInitializer - how it works and what may go wrong](http://stefan-isele.logdown.com/posts/201646)

**Startup of servlet contexts without web.xml**

Servlets of release 3 can be configured programatically, without any `web.xml`.
With Spring and its Java-configuration you create a configuration class that implements `org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer`.
Spring will automatically find all classes that implement this interface and start the according servlet contexts. More excatly its not Spring that searches for those classes, its the servlet container (e.g. jetty or tomcat ).
The class `org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer` is annotated with
`@javax.servlet.annotation.HandlesTypes(WebApplicationInitializer.class`)
and implements `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`
According to the Servlet 3 specification the container will call `org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Set<Class<?>>, ServletContext)` on every class in the classpath implementing that interface, suppling a set of classes as defined in HandlesTypes

**Startup order, if there is more than one context**

If there is more than one class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer`, the order in which they are started can be controlled with the annotation `org.springframework.core.Ordered` .

**Things that may go wrong**

**Different Spring versions in the classpath**

If you have different versions of `WebApplicationInitializer` in the classpath, the servlet container may scan for the classes implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` of **version 'A'** while your configuration classes implement `WebApplicationInitializer` of **version 'B'**. And than your configuration classes will not be found and the sercletontexts will not be started.

**Unexpected WebApplicationInitializers in the classpath**

Do not package any `WebApplicationInitializers` into jars or wars that you later may have in the classpath of other web applications. They may get found and started when you do not expect it. This happend to me when I packed `WebApplicationInitializers` with Maven into test-jars, which were reused by other tests.

**To many classes in the classpath**

The servlet container has to scan the classpath, and the more classes, the longer it takes.
At least Jetty has a build in timeout, so you may get an

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException thrown by
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer
```

> The solution is to tell jetty which jars to scan. This will make the
>   startup much faster and avoids the timeout. In Maven you can do it
>   like this :

### pom.xml

```
<plugin>
     <groupId> org.eclipse.jetty</groupId >
     <artifactId> jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId >
     <configuration>
     <webAppConfig>
         <contextPath> /${project.artifactId}</contextPath >
         <webInfIncludeJarPattern> busines-letter-*.</webInfIncludeJarPattern >
     </webAppConfig>
```

**Spring logging**

When you have logging configured you should find one of the following entries in your log :

If Spring finds no `WebApplicationInitializer` at all, you will see in the log :

```
No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

If Spring finds at least one `WebApplicationInitializer` you will see :

```
Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: " + initializers
```