# equivalent web.xml for WebApplicationInitializers class?

Tags: java, spring

what is the equivalent of web.xml for WebApplicationInitializers class?

```
   package com.concretepage.config;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
    public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
        }
        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since AppConfig in rootConfig, it should be loaded via  ContextLoaderListener

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- For root context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

     <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>package.AppConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>



</web-app>
```

Comment: i am getting "No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath" in server log file

Comment: possibly you may having source compatibility check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938689/info-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath