# INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath (jre 1.8)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I got this error message from putty:

> Error: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath.

When I deploy WAR file using eclipse and maven. Right now I'm using jre 1.8 and tomcat version 7. I checked compiler and its version is 1.8. Is there any solution for this problem? I also enabled the option build automatically.

These are the error messages I got from putty

> 17-Jan-2017 17:50:03.587 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9485"]
>
> 17-Jan-2017 17:50:11.982 INFO [ruthhere.cafe24.com-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>
> 17-Jan-2017 17:50:11.989 INFO [ruthhere.cafe24.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938689/info-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem just right now. The reason why I kept getting this error is because the java version I have and java version in the eclipse project property were mismatched. 
First, I checked the java version that I have. than opened pom.xml and changed java version so that it can match with the java version.

```
<java-version>1.7</java-version>
```

Also, I checked window >properties > project facets and changed java version too.