# Manual war deployment to Jetty to run a web application.

Tags: jetty-9

I have Jetty server directory and manually copied the war file to the /webapps directory but when I run the start.jar from command prompt, I get the below error. I have JETTY_HOME set for the PATH variable too.

```
2017-02-09 12:28:48.940:INFO::main: Logging initialized @871ms
2017-02-09 12:28:49.010:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty i
s not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.
See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.
html
2017-02-09 12:28:49.220:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.16.v20170120
2017-02-09 12:28:49.240:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor
[file:///C:/Users/u458714/Desktop/jetty-distribution-9.3.16.v20170120/webapps/]
at interval 1
2017-02-09 12:28:54.743:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed
 time=3354ms
2017-02-09 12:28:55.192:INFO:C.0:main: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types
 detected on classpath
Feb 09, 2017 12:28:56 PM com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.lang.NullPointerExcept
ion
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.wellsfargo.wria2.environment.EnvironmentModule.configure(Environm
entModule.java:74)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:
223)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
        at com.wellsfargo.wria2.taglib.CoreRendererModule.configure(CoreRenderer
Module.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:
223)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:118)
        at com.wellsfargo.wria2.taglib.Wria2JspTagLibraryModule.configure(Wria2J
spTagLibraryModule.java:18)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:
223)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.
java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInje
ctorCreator.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
        at com.wellsfargo.wria2.jsp.WT2ServletContextListener.contextInitialized
(WT2ServletContextListener.java:94)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialize
d(ContextHandler.java:843)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialize
d(ServletContextHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextH
andler.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletC
ontextHandler.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java
:1404)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.jav
a:1366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandle
r.java:778)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContex
tHandler.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520
)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(Stan
dardStarter.java:41)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:1
88)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentM
anager.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.j
ava:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(Scan
ningAppProvider.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppPro
vider.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(Sc
anningAppProvider.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(Scanni
ngAppProvider.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(Deploymen
tManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.
java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLi
feCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(Container
LifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHand
ler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLife
Cycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:15
16)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:144
1)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

Comment: Could you share more information about your server configuration? Also, it looks like you are using Spring, correct? Regarding the Spring error (`No Spring WebApplicationInitialize types detected`) this seems to have cropped up a few times on SO and looks to be due to JVM/Java version mismatches.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938689/info-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711391/info-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath-jre-1-8