# Continuously getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am struggling to solve the below exception:

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 17, 2017 8:48:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ApplicationListener@1e856aa
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1465)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1310)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:513)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5288)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1380)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Apr 17, 2017 8:48:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Apr 17, 2017 8:48:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

I am using maven and added below dependency to solve this but not getting result, still facing same issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I already added the maven dependency. For Spring and Hibernate I have added all the required dependency.

Comment: Referring to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938689/info-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath)

Comment: @vikram 1) Please add the whole pom.xml here. 2) are you using JSF in your project ?

Comment: @PratikShah I am not using JSF in my project. PFB pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not on your dependencies. I am new to spring too but i think this might help you:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

     @Override
     public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
         AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
         context.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

         ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
         dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
         dispatcher.addMapping("/");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is saying that the class is not found, then it's actually saying that the class can not be loaded by the JVM, because the JVM can not find that class in your classpath.

Then you need to build your project again with maven, in order to create .class files for your JVM,

Or before that, try to pull again your project dependencies from remote maven repository into your local maven repository, and then do the maven build project in order to populate .class files.

Hope that this helps.