# apache tomcat 8.0.9 is not starting suddenly

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am using eclipse and tomcat. I was unable to start tomcat server. It showed a problem encountered and server couldn't be started. Moreover, I tried to start by using command prompt and still failed. I already restarted my PC and changed Tomcat's port, but it still having problem. While I start the server, a part of eclipse's consoles message shows:

```
Sep 02, 2014 8:09:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Sep 02, 2014 8:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FirstSpringMVCProject]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Is there a stack trace with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664924/only-one-error-no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath

Comment: Did you do a "clean" on the server runtime to fully redeploy your application and any configuration files Eclipse may have overridden?

Comment: @Dave: too many. this is why i didn't give it here.

Comment: @Joey: Sorry,I am not getting it.

Comment: @Gimby: Last time I was just following this tutorial. http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/
but it didn't do a problem then.

Comment: @Mahin, can you paste in some of the stack trace.  Also see if any of it originates with your web application.

Comment: @Dave: I've added those in the question.please check.

Comment: I think you are having problem with your web.xml file

Comment: @ practice2perfect: I think my web.xml file is ok.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but some looking around suggests trying to increase the tomcat log level (http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/increase-tomcat-logging-verbosity-quick-problem-resolution).  Another cause of this was a library compiled with java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in an app,that was running in the server that time. Because of the problematic app server was not running.After removing the app from the server,server started running again. So,this is not a problem of server,but of app.