# Apache Tomcat and Apache TomEE server is not running web projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat, apache-tomee

At first I'm apologizing for asking same question twice. First time I didn't get any answer. Then I tried myself to solve the problem,but failed. This is why I'm asking the question again and this time I'm putting it briefly.
I was learning Spring MVC framework by myself. I was using jdk 8.20 version, tomcat 8.0.9 version and eclipse luna. At first everything was working smoothly. But all of a sudden my tomcat server installed in eclipse stopped working. I was failed to run it using cmd or startup.bat too.

Problem asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625694/apache-tomcat-8-0-9-is-not-starting-suddenly). After that I tried myself and I changed the server. I used tomcat 7 and TomEE 1.7.0. Every time my server started smoothly, I installed the server in eclipse smoothly. But whenever I tried to create a project and run it, eclipse couldn't use the server anymore. Even after attempting to run a project, eclipse couldn't start it by start command. But the difference between tomcat8 and TomEE is I can now run it outside of eclipse   using startup.bat. I also tried changing the port number,but that didn't work either.

For TomEE first it showed unable to read zip file `spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE-javadoc`. Then I replaced all the spring files, now it showing a container failed to start.

Here is my console output:

```
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\bin;E:\IDE\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32_2\eclipse;;.
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebChatApp' did not find a matching property.
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 820 ms
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebChatApp]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebChatApp]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name spring-dispatcher
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3294)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3273)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1344)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 11, 2014 12:18:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>
  index.jsp
</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="HandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>


<bean name="/welcome.htm" 
class="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller.HelloController" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Here is a portion of my catalina log file:

```
Sep 11, 2014 12:14:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\bin;.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:04 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: OpenEJB http://openejb.apache.org/
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Startup: Thu Sep 11 12:15:05 ALMT 2014
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Copyright 1999-2013 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Version: 4.7.0
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build date: 20140810
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: Build time: 12:40
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: ********************************************************************************
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.home = C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance <init>
INFO: openejb.base = C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@1717824
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initializeOWB
INFO: Succeeded in installing singleton service
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory init
INFO: openejb configuration file is 'C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\conf\tomee.xml'
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.system.apps=true'
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:05 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: openejb
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Using openejb.deploymentId.format '{ejbName}'
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb openejb/Deployer: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb openejb/ConfigurationInfo: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb MEJB: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFO: Configuring Service(id=Default Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig createContainer
INFO: Auto-creating a container for bean openejb/Deployer: Container(type=STATELESS, id=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "openejb" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Container(id=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: openejb
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:06 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.jndiname.format={deploymentId}{interfaceType.openejbLegacyName}'
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=openejb/ConfigurationInfoBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/ConfigurationInfo!org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.cmd.ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/MEJB!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/openejb/MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=MEJB, container=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, container=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=MEJB, container=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, container=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler startEjbs
INFO: Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Stateless Container)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler deployMBean
INFO: Deployed MBean(openejb.user.mbeans:application=openejb,group=org.apache.openejb.assembler.monitoring,name=JMXDeployer)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=openejb)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:07 PM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager initServer
INFO: Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO:   ** Bound Services **
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager printRow
INFO:   NAME                 IP              PORT  
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: -------
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: Ready!
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 9618 ms
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener bindResource
INFO: Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.55 (1.7.0)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\docs
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:08 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /docs
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\docs
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\docs" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\docs
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFO: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@1717824
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 234 ms.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:09 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\docs)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\docs has finished in 2,198 ms
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\host-manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /host-manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\host-manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\host-manager" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\host-manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFO: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@1717824
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 12 ms.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder deployWebApps
INFO: using context file C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\host-manager\META-INF\context.xml
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:10 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\host-manager)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\host-manager has finished in 491 ms
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\manager" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\manager
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFO: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@1717824
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFO: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer validateInjectionPoints
INFO: All injection points were validated successfully.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFO: OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 10 ms.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder deployWebApps
INFO: using context file C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\manager)
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\manager has finished in 341 ms
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\ROOT
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\ROOT
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFO: Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\ROOT" loaded.
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plus-1.7.0\webapps\ROOT
Sep 11, 2014 12:15:11 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the server, the problem is your application. The key is the following line of your traces:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name spring-dispatcher
```

And the reason for that is the following line on your web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You don't have a servlet element on your web.xml with the name `spring-dispatcher`. The only one you have has the name `FirstSpringMVCProject`. These two values (servlet-name) have to be equal.

Comment: I've changed both name to spring-dispatcher .But server still not running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in an app that was running in the server that time. Because of the problematic app the server was not running. After removing the app from the server, the server started running again. So, this is not a problem of the server, but of the app.