# tomcat-maven-plugin webapps path don't have war

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

**Images Links:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9psl.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N3QQ.png

---

my project not Add to the webapps.

logs don't print the springframework log

localhost:8080/index.do  404

[use the tomcat server it can works(Project has not error),  tomcat-maven-plugin can't]

Comment: Try to run tomcat7:run-war or tomcat7:deploy  from your command line or IDE

Comment: Based on the error messages in your first screenshot, it looks like Spring is not finding a Web Application Initializer on the classpath after Tomcat starts up. So your issue is **not** with Tomcat, but your Spring configuration and/or general web app configuration. Take a look at the following 3 Stavkoverflow questions and see if they help. If not, you will need to provide more information about your configurations, such as your web.xml content, and your Spring Context file. 
1) http://stackoverflow.com/q/22938689
2) http://stackoverflow.com/q/16321819
3) http://stackoverflow.com/q/16664924